# Dump core if SIGSEGV (in C)?

Tags: c, linux

How can I dump the core when my program receives the SIGSEGV signal ? (The server that runs my program has very limited permissions and therefore core dump is disabled by default.)

I have written the following using gcore but I would like to use C functions instead. Can I somehow catch the core and write it to a folder somewhere ?

```
void segfaulthandler(int parameter)
{
    char gcore[50];
    sprintf(gcore, "gcore -s -c \"core\" %u", getpid());
    system(gcore);

    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, segfaulthandler);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's a hard limit preventing you, you could use `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, ...)` to increase the softlimit and enable coredumps - this corresponds to running `ulimit -c` in shell.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, you typically can do:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

The resulting core file will be written in the current working directory of the process when the signal is received.

Comment: The core file will be created based on the current working directory, using the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` - which defaults to simply "core"

Comment: Also, `/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid` can be set to 1, in that case .pid is appended to the corefile name (unless the pattern contains %p)